# Minecraft version 1.8.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can find no release notes about version 1.8.9, yet, my installer just downloaded it today.

What is the purpose/features of this update?

I ask, because the minecraft GUI doesn't announce the update (it always does), there is no update on the Wiki (it always does) and I want to be sure something bad isn't happening to my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searge on Twitter ([source](https://twitter.com/SeargeDP/status/674522783574056960)):

> We are going to update Minecraft 1.8.8 to 1.8.9 later today. The only changes are related to better Realms integration. Nothing else changed

Answer (score 2):

Mojang created the update to improve realms, and nothing else. They didn't announce it because it wasn't really all that important, and it didn't belong on the update tree.

I'm sticking to 1.8.8 right now, just because not many people mess with profile settings (I do though and that's how I found out), and I'd rather keep things simple and less confusing.  Plus servers run easier if you are on the preferred version.